# what happens if one of the synthetic partition key not available to query azure cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, partitioning

we are discussing and identifying issues over synthetic partition key in cosmos db, Lets assume from the MS example that I have the synthetic partition key is a mix of deviceId-date what happens to the RU consumption and performance when one of the value is not there for example few queries may run without the deviceid field value and few run with date.

```
{
"deviceId": "abc-123",
"date": 2018,
"partitionKey": "abc-123-2018"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't pass the entire value you will have a fan out (cross partition query).

There is a solution for this with hierarchical partition keys. However, this is a hierarchy, if you have the top and third layer and miss the second, it will still span all partitions under the top layer. You will get nothing if you pass the lowest child in the hierarchy.

This is in preview now. Can learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/hierarchical-partition-keys)

Comment: Yes, true. but unfortunately we are using mongo db and AFAIK hierarchical keys is available in only SQL for now

Comment: could you please point me to docs where is it available "If you don't pass the entire value you will have a fan out (cross partition query)."

Comment: adding it for further references for all. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/6fbbbdb2989c2b86a6070b2b75575a40f127627f/articles/cosmos-db/hierarchical-partition-keys.md#example-use-case

Comment: Not sure its documented but it's an obvious assertion. Partition key values must match for the request to get routed correctly. It must be an equality, you can't use a "StartsWith" or similar string matching with a partition key.

Comment: This is probably the closest thing that documents why you cannot use a partial match for the partition key value. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#managing-logical-partitions  The value itself is hashed. If you pass in a partial match the hash would be different and Cosmos would not know where to route the query.